# Setup or "set up"?

Tags: verbs, orthography, phrasal-verbs, technology

The word *setup* (as a noun), I feel, has become an acceptable part of the English language, at least insofar as technical manuals or computer textbooks are concerned. However I find that the word is used very often in verb form like so:

> "You can setup the program quite easily ..."

when in fact my understanding is that the actual sentence should be:

> "You can set up the program quite easily ..."

I would like to know if *setup* can be used as a verb. The situation seems be very similar to the word *output* (as a noun). *Output* is a purely technical word and its use is restricted solely to technical texts or at least in a technical context within non-technical books. However it is also used in verb form now like so:

> "The system will output the signal ..."

I would be very grateful if this question is answered. Thank you

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=setup+vs+%22set+up%22

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set_up: verb, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/setup: noun. Illiteracy is a thing, so are typos. That is all.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the use of "setup" as a verb - in writing - is mostly due to laziness, not wanting to add a space.

Consider pronunciation though. When I speak, at least, "setup" comes out more quickly and the emphasis is on the *e*. When I say "set up", it's a bit slower because of the word separation and the emphasis is on the *u*, if anywhere. Do you hear that as well in conversation?

In any case, grammatically, I find no version of "setup" that could be used as a verb, and all the dictionaries I've checked so far have it down as a noun.

Comment: That's an interesting observation about the pronunciation. Although I have been pedantic about using "set up" in writing, I must confess to using "setup" in speech.